# Ember Component with a text field

Tags: ember.js, components

I have an ember component which wraps a text field. When a user types I want to fire of a search action.

```
#search-box.js.coffee
App.SearchBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  classNames: ['form-group', 'has-feedback']
  term: ""
  placeholder: "Search"

  actions:
    search: ->
      console.log "Searching..."

# search-box.emblem
= input type="text" value=term class="form-control" placeholder=placeholder keyUp="search"
```

This maintains the binding between value and term, but the keyUp event goes to the Ember Input component and does not bubble to the search-box component. If I drop the `=` and instead use a standard HTML input, I get the action sent to the right component, but the binding breaks and I lose my search term.

What's the proper way to use an input with an action inside a component?

**EDIT: Another approach**

Trying to do it with JQuery, with the added difficulty of searching after a specified period of inactivity (a second, in this case):

```
App.SearchBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  classNames: ['form-group', 'has-feedback']
  delay: 1000
  didInsertElement: ->
    $input = @$('input')
    $input.on 'keyup', =>
      clearTimeout(timer)
      if $input.val
        console.log this
        timer = setTimeout(@_performSearch, @get('delay')
  _performSearch: ->
    console.log this
    console.log "Searching for #{@get('q')}"
```

When `_performSearch` is called, `this` is now `window` and has lost the context of the Ember class. I also tried making everything fat arrows to make absolutely sure no function changes the context of `this`, but to no avail. It will work if I make an anonymous function inside of the setTimeout call, but not if I call a method on the ember object.

Comment: good luck using ember's keyUp, i have never got that to work... but perhaps if you make a component that extends the actual textfield view. you can use the actual javascript keyup event to trigger some behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a jQuery mouse event in the `didInsertElement` hook of the component:

```
App.SearchBoxComponent = Ember.Component.extend
  classNames: ['form-group', 'has-feedback']
  term: ""
  placeholder: "Search"

  didInsertElement: ->
    @$('input').keyup => 
      console.log 'Searching...'
```

Regarding your second approach, you can specify the context of the function by using [`Ember.run.later`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later). Note: you were also missing closing parentheses after your call to `setTimeout`.

Replace

```
timer = setTimeout(@_performSearch, @get('delay'))
```

with

```
Ember.run.later(@,@_performSearch, @get('delay'))
```

Comment: I had something like this in an earlier iteration of this code, but abandoned it because somehow I was losing the context of the ember class in a subsequent method call, and I was hoping for a non-jquery solution. I'll give this another go.

Comment: I have a different approach that has some issues that I added above. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented the same search mechanics by observing value of `search_term` (`term` in your code). I think you could try to do it that way. You need to set observer in `App.SearchBoxComponent`, firing `search` action from there, if `!Em.Empty(this.get('term')`.